# Displaying ??? instead of characters

Tags: android

I use this code to ask for a language to the user:

```
void AskForLanguage() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose a language");
    final String[] arrsLanguages;

    arrsLanguages = new String[6];
    arrsLanguages[0] = "English";
    arrsLanguages[1] = "Español (Spanish)";
    arrsLanguages[2] = "Français (French)";
    arrsLanguages[3] = "Pусский язык (Russian)";
    arrsLanguages[4] = "العربية (Arabic)";
    arrsLanguages[5] = "简体中文 (Simplified Chinese)";

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(arrsLanguages, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int iPosition) {
            //Do some work
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

It works well for texts like English, Español and Français, but the dialog displays "?" symbols for Russian, Arabic or Chinese. Any idea?

Comment: looks weird i use persian all the time,cause arabic and chinese and russian have different apabelt symbol make sure string is utf8

Comment: With utf8 even Español and Français are displayed wrongly. So I had to use iso-8859-1

Comment: maybe your phone or emulator doesn't support those languages

Comment: Yes, it supports. Because once I choose the language and set the locale. The app restarts displaying everything in Russian, or Arabic or Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the strings.xml file:

```
<string name="RussianInRussian">"Pусский язык (Russian)"</string>
<string name="ChineseInChinese">"简体中文 (Simplified Chinese)"</string>
```

And then

```
arrsLanguages[3] = getString(R.string.RussianInRussian); 
arrsLanguages[5] = getString(R.string.ChineseInChinese);
```

Comment: strange behavier

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
arrsLanguages[5] = URLDecoder.decode("简体中文 (Simplified Chinese)", "utf-8");
```

sometimes your device may not be supporting `Español` font, so try downloading some `Español` **ttf** (fonts) and set them to check if its getting displayed

Comment: It is even worse. Now it displays symbols like P%3F%3F... by the way I used "URLEncoder.encode" because "URLEncoder.decode" didn't exist

Comment: URLDecoder.decode("Pусский язык (Russian)", "utf-8"); results as "P??????? ????? (Russian)"

Comment: please try downloading `ttf` files for **russian**